# How to know when a recursive function has stopped calling itself?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, settimeout

Is there any way to know when a recursive function has stopped calling itself?

I have the following scenario:

```
function print(msg){
  console.log(msg);
  
  if(canContinue){
    print("Hi there");
  }

  if(canContinueCase2){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      print("I was late to the party");
    }, 2000);
  }

  if(canContinueCase3){
    print("Cool right?");
  }

  if(canContinueCase4){
    if(canContinueCase5 && !otherBoolean){
      print("Thank you!");
    }
  }
}
```

`canContinue`, `canContinueCase2`, ... `otherBoolean` are global variables (booleans). How would one know when the function `print(msg)` is no longer being called? In other words how can I know that the algorithm has stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a counter:

```js
let counter = 0;

function print(msg){
  console.log(msg);
  
  if(canContinue){
    counter++;
    print("Hi there");
  }

  if(canContinueCase2){
    counter++;
    setTimeout(()=>{
      print("I was late to the party");
    }, 2000);
  }

  if(canContinueCase3){
    counter++;
    print("Cool right?");
  }

  if(canContinueCase4){
    if(canContinueCase5 && !otherBoolean){
      counter++;
      print("Thank you!");
    }
  }
  counter--;
}

counter++;
print("hi");

//to check if the function is done, use this:
if (counter == 0) {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test the booleans at the start all together. If any one of them === true it's not `finished`

```
function print(msg){
  let finished = !(canContinue || canContinueCase2 || canContinueCase3 || canContinueCase4 || canContinueCase5 || otherBoolean);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I think that this is not what he meant. look on my answer.

Comment: @Ofek - OP alluded to the variables being booleans which, once satisfied, would equal false. But I'll let OP clarify if I'm mistaken

Comment: You can't know if canContinueCase2 were false at the last 2 seconds...

Comment: Also, it should be !(... || canContinueCase3 || (canContinueCase4 && canContinueCase5 && !otherBoolean))

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. last 2 seconds of what? There's no scenario here. Also your nested conditional isn't any different from mine in substance - all booleans must be false to be satisfied. Really, this is all academic and speculative until OP gives an actual use case and we see how the logic is processed.

Comment: I mean, The functions are calling async, and you can't know if setTimeout is done or not

Comment: I see. ok, I glossed over the setTimeout.